# Access the Stage from within the controller

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

How can the `Stage` be accessed form within the controller which is assigned to the `View`?

Currently I use a setter from outside the controller to set the stage but I would like to know if there is a way where I do not need to rely on explicitly called methods from outside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any node references in your controller, you can:

```
Stage theStage = (Stage) nodeReference.getScene().getWindow();
```

Be careful using this. Stage is a subclass of Window, so Stage is a Window, but a Window may not always be a Stage.

Comment: At what time in the life cycle can this be called? I guess it is not available during `@FXML initialize() {..}` ...

Comment: No, you'd have to be already attached to the scene graph. If you need access to the stage earlier, I would inject it on creation of your controller.

Comment: That's what I thought and that's what I am doing right now, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.